# Display Custom format value on page layouts

Tags: page-layout

I'm creating page layouts in SharePoint 2013. 
I have added author field in page layout.But I have to display First And Last Name of Author.

```
<SharePoint:FormField ID="FormField1" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Author" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
```

Also I have SharePoint Date-time control

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="14aa28de-f5fa-48cc-8f8a-ac7d4a215136" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField>
```

I'm trying to display custom date on page layout like **May 11th 2017**

Please suggest something

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding `SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField` you can just render the code in-line

```
<%=SPContext.Current.ListItem["Created"] != null? (new DateTime(SPContext.Current.ListItem["Created"].ToString()).ToString("USE FORMAT DATE STRING HERE"): string.Empty %>
```

OR

Create a calculated column to store the date and render that field
The formula for calculated column will be `=TEXT(DATEFIELD,"DATEFORMAT")`